# Remove a key in the Dictionary and reload a TableView in Swift 2

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, nsdictionary, nsindexpath

I am creating an app that has a UITableView in a ViewController. The data that will be presented at TableView are in an NSDictionary.

Let me explain how my project is to then ask my question:
[image]

And my Swift Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var dict:[Int:String] = [:]
    var count:Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dict.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.label.text = self.dict[indexPath.row]! as String
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Remove?", message: "Touch in Remove", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let remove =  UIAlertAction(title: "Remove", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                self.dict.removeValueForKey(indexPath.row)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(cancel)
            alert.addAction(remove)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        dict[count] = "Row \(count)"
        ++count
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

When I tap the Add button, a key is generated in ascending order (var count) and a value = "Row (1)." This is working perfectly.

The next step is for removal. Added a Swipe to remove the row and it works perfectly.

However, when I recharge the table by tableView.reload (), an error is displayed.

The message is:

> fatal error: nil unexpectedly found while unwrapping an Optional value

I found where the error but I can not fix occurs.

The error is a result of removing a key in NSDicionary. When I recharge my table, indexPath.row takes the data dict[indexPath.row], but this key does not exist.

Example: If you remove the line with the key 2, when reloading the table, the fatal error will occur when you pick up the key 2 data in the dictionary.

I tried to validate that there is such a key in the dictionary, but the table displays an empty line. And I need not display any rows.

My question: **When we work with keys and dicionaries together with the TableView, how can we return or not to display a nonexistent line?**

Comment: Do you have to use a `Dictionary`. `Arrays` and `TableViews` go together like peanut butter and jelly.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use an `Array` if you can. If not, you could try 1) making the cell that would be empty hidden before returning it (that should avoid an empty line), or 2)  rebuilding the dictionary to avoid the empty row (kind of gross but maybe doable if it isn't going to contain too many items).

Comment: @mcclux Currently, hiding the cell would not work because his `numberOfRowsInSection` is based on `dict.count`. If he had 3 items and he removed the second item, the third would not display because `indexPath.row` would only increment to 1. He could technically use his `count` variable and it would work, but he should not be using a `Dictionary` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go an array of Tuples, incase you really wanted to use that Int value. If you don't need it then just make it an array like others said.

```
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var tuple = [(Int,String)]()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tuple.count
    }

        cell.label.text = tuple[indexPath.row].1
        return cell
    }


    self.dict2.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)


    @IBAction func addAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        tuple += [(count,"Row \(count)")]
        ++count
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: I'm thinking of using arrays, but need to store data as a dictionary, why not just involve a String. My dictionary has the information age as well, and may involve more data until the end of the project. I could continue to use dictionaries or should find another way to organize my data?

Comment: You can use tuples to associate say you have a person with age, address, phone number, description etc. Tuples will be great for that. 
`var myTuples = [(Age:Int,Name:String,Address:String,strength:Double)]()

myTuples += [(10,"Dan","123 fake Street",3.2)]

myTuples[0].Age

myTuples[0].strength`